# format a string to a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string formatted as:

```
s = "[2153.   3330.75]"
```

I'd like to convert to a list with `ints`.

Expected output: `l = [2153, 3330]`

`type(l)` is `list`

Comment: How do you get this string? This does not look like any standard data format.

Comment: `l = [int(float(x)) for x in s[1:-1].split()]` but again this should not be the way to go.

Comment: Are you in control of the code that is generating the string in the first place?  It would be better to use a standard serialization such as JSON so you don't have to write your own ad hoc parser to read the values back in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does what you are looking for.

```py
l = [int(float(x)) for x in s.strip('[]').split()]
```

The float conversion is required because strings containing "." cannot be converted directly to integers.

Comment: you can convert straight to ints

Comment: @Matt no you can't. `int('1.0')` throws a `ValueError`

Comment: no you can't https://onecompiler.com/python/3y794apzq

Comment: @Matt no, you're convertign a `float` to an `int`. The problem at hand here is to convert a *string* to an int.

Comment: oh you're right, I was thinking of just doing `int(1.)` but it's a string

Answer (score 4):

The string looks like a numpy array.
First, we convert the string to a float numpy array using numpy `fromstring` method. Then convert the float array to `int` array using `astype` method. Finally, convert the numpy array to a `list` using `tolist` method:

```
import numpy as np

s = "[2153.   3330.75]"
values = np.fromstring(s[1:-1], dtype=float, sep=' ').astype(int).tolist()
print(values)
```

**Output:**

```
[2153, 3330]
```

**References:**

- [Documentation on numpy fromstring method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy-fromstring)
- [Documentation on numpy astype method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html?highlight=astype#numpy-ndarray-astype)
- [Documentation on numpy tolist method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html?highlight=tolist#numpy.ndarray.tolist)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using `lambda` functions.

```
num = list(map(lambda x: int(float(x)), s.strip("[]").split()))
```

Here, `s.strip("[]")` remove the square brackets. We use `lambda` functions to convert all `float` to `int`.

We use `int(float(x))` instead of `int(x)` because otherwise we get `ValueError` when we are converting "2153." to `int`.